# Why Process destroy cannot work when exec bat but not exe

Tags: java, batch-file, process, exe, destroy

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "C:/work/bat/ConsoleApplication1.exe" });
Thread.sleep(4000);
p.destroy();
int res = p.waitFor();
System.out.println("res" + res);
```

This will print `res1` and JVM will be stoped at one time, but if like this :

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "C:/work/bat/exe.bat" });
```

This will also print `res1` after about **4s** but JVM will not be stopped at one time. JVM will stop after more **6s**.

This is **exe.bat**

```
 C:\work\bat\ConsoleApplication1.exe
```

This is **ConsoleApplication1.exe**:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
int a=0;
while(a<100){
    Sleep(100);
    cout<<a++ <<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

So, how can I stop the bat file like exe file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to kill the process. Find process id and use it with `taskkill` command.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("taskkill " +<Your process id>);
```

But it works in Windows. For Linux use this -

```
rt.exec("kill -9 " +<Your process id>);
```

Comment: Hi, I have use "tasklist /v" to see the process list. But I can only see "ConsoleApplication1.exe" but not "exe.bat" when I use bat. So, how can I stop one bat includes more than one exe command ?

Comment: Thanks, but I need run a bat file which comes from user, so I don't know which exe will be called in this bat. In my code, I will run a bat and stop it if timeout, but I find I cannot stop the exe which be called by the bat.